# Django: dynamic ModelchoiceField not saving

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following Model ChoiceFIeld

```
class ad(ModelForm):

    REGION = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = REGION.objects.all())
    CITY = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = CITY.objects.all())
    ZIP = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = ZIP.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = myinfo
    fields = ('REGION', 'CITY', 'ZIP',)
```

The `CITY` and `ZIP` is being filled dynamically by javascript and I am having a problem saving as `form.is_valid` is returning false and thus not saved unless I remove `CITY` and `ZIP`, what am I doing wrong?

my views

```
def index(request):
    city = CITY.objects.all()
    zip = ZIP.objects.all()

    form = ad(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':


        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = ad()

    return render(request, 'dynamic/sample.html', {'adform':form, 'city': city, 'zip': zip,})
```

my javascript

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function removeOptions(selectbox)
            {
                var i;
                for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
                {
                    selectbox.remove(i);
                }
            }
            removeOptions(document.getElementById("id_CITY"));
            removeOptions(document.getElementById("id_ZIP"));
            $("#id_CITY").append("<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">---------</option>");
            $("#id_ZIP").append("<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">---------</option>");
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#id_REGION").change(function() {
                var el = $(this);
                function removeOptions(selectbox)
                {
                    var i;
                    for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
                    {
                        selectbox.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                removeOptions(document.getElementById("id_CITY"));
                removeOptions(document.getElementById("id_ZIP"));
                $("#id_CITY").append("<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">---------</option>");
                $("#id_ZIP").append("<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">---------</option>");

                var reg = [{% for item in city %}"{{ item.reg_id }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];
                var city_name = [{% for item in city %}"{{ item.name }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

                for(var i = 0; i<reg.length; i++){
                    if(el.val() == reg[i]){
                        $("#id_CITY").append("<option value = \"" + city_name[i] + "\">" + city_name[i] + "</option>");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#id_CITY").change(function() {
                var el = $(this);
                function removeOptions(selectbox)
                {
                    var i;
                    for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
                    {
                        selectbox.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                removeOptions(document.getElementById("id_ZIP"));
                $("#id_ZIP").append("<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">---------</option>");

                var zip = [{% for item in zip %}"{{ item.cit }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];
                var zip_num = [{% for item in zip %}"{{ item.num }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

                for(var i = 0; i<zip.length; i++){
                    if(el.val() == zip[i]){
                        $("#id_ZIP").append("<option value = \"" + zip_num[i] + "\">" + zip_num[i] + "</option>");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may not be related to your problem, but you have some name conflicts going on.  In your model form, you have fields named CITY, REGION and ZIP, but you also seem to have models of those names as well.  Try renaming one or the other.  Also, `zip` is the name of a built-in python function.  Try renaming your `zip` variable to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get True on calling form.is_valid(), city which the user have chosen must be a member of queryset CITY.objects.none().  Same thing is applicable for zip also.  This is not possible.

Try:

```
1. Put CITY.objects.all(), ZIP.objects.all() as querysets
2. Remove all options using js
2. Fill required options
```

Comment: It's still not saving, but i have discovered that if `ZIP` and `CITY` is a field and not a modelchoice field it works, also if i remove the javascript it also works, I'll update my question to include my script